# UICollectionViewCell index number not accurate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to display a question mark in every even location of a cell in UICollectionView

I wrote like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (indexPath.row %2 ==0){
                UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 20, 20)];
                [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"missing"]];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:image];
          }

        return cell;

}
```

On the first time that I see the UICollectionView - the image is being displayed property - on every even number : 0,2,4 but as I start scrolling horizontal right and left the pictures is being added to almost every cell regardless my condition: `indexPath.row %2 ==0`

How can I prevent it? How can I make sure that even during scrolling the index path wouldn't be changed?

I am writing for ios7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your old cells are getting reused, and you don't reset their appearance. Add an `else` block to your `if` condition in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, and clean up your cell there, e.g. by removing the image view from the cell, or something like that.

What you want is something like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPath.row %2 ==0){
        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 20, 20)];
        [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"missing"]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:image];
    }
    else { 
        // Code to clean up the cell goes here.
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How do I remove the picture?

Comment: You have a few options. One is to create a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`, and add a property for the image view there. Then you can easily reference it via that property. Another approach is to add a tag to the image view when you add it, so when you want to remove it, you can find it by that tag while iterating through the cell's subviews.

Comment: Thanks - I just wrote  for (UIView *view in cell.subviews)
            {
                if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
                    [view removeFromSuperview];
            }

Comment: Yeah, if you only have one image view in each cell, that will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
   UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 20, 20)];

  if (indexPath.row %2 ==0){

  ```
  [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"missing"]];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:image];
  ```

  }
  else 
  {

  ```
  [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:image];
  ```

  }

  return cell;
  }